# Compiling .Net Compact Framework projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

When I run my project in build server it fails with this reason.

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  [project name].csproj

But it runs successfully in my local machine.

I think problem is that windows Compact Framework does not support for 64 bit.

How do I reseolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe list the differences between your local machine and your build server. That might provide enough information for someone to help you identify the problem.

Comment: My Local machine and build server also x64 bit, There is no difference.